# Can I create company hub app for windows 10 mobile app distribution?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal, company-hub

I had created company hub app for Win Phone 8 where signed xap is downladed from a url on mobile devices with preinstalled AET token.

But I am not able to find similar mechanism for distributing Windows10 UWP/ Windows-10 mobile app.

How can this be achieved? How to distribute WP10 apps without using store.

Comment: question update in more detail. not clear out

Comment: We can have two ways to publish Windows (Phone) app-

1 Publish app on Windows Store - The usual way.
2 Publish through company hub app(for internal use of a company/enterprise- My question is regarding this)
Company hub app is an app created for distributing the 'actual app' to a group of users.
How option2 is currently achieved -->

1. The company registers for a company developer account and then acquires an enterprise certificate from Symantec.
2. The company creates an application enrollment token (AET).
3. The company develops a Company Hub app.

Comment: 4. Employees (or other users) enroll for company app distribution on their phones by installing AET and then install the xap of 'main app'using the Company Hub app. Anyone without AET will not be able to install the the main app.

a link for more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296515.aspx

All this was avilable for WP8, Is this mechanism (Company hub app) available in Windows 10 for UWP ?

Comment: Waiting for any update / answer to the query... experts . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Amit, with Windows 10 (Mobile) you still have the option to distribute your app via Company Portal (e.g. the name for Microsoft Intune Mobile Application Management app for users to get internal company apps). With Windows 10 Mobile you don't need the Symantec certificate anymore.

In addition, you can distribute your app through Windows Store for Business web portal new with Windows 10 devices (please see http://businessstore.microsoft.com).

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for the answer. Windows Business store is not an option for me as the app would need to go through same certification process as any store app.(as my app uses certian apis not ok for store apps ). So you mean  I need to use MDM like MS Intune to deploy app on the company Win10 Mobile devices ?